# Repaint() not repainting

Tags: java, repaint

I seem to not completely understand the paintcomponent method including the use of repaint.
Several times i do not get why repaint not working in some code, while working fine in another.
im trying to create a Graph painting class. right now its y=x. but it won't work. the paintcomponent seemed to be called just once. why is that?

```
public class Graph extends JPanel
{
    private int oldX=0,oldY=0,newX=1,newY=1;
    public Graph()
    {
        invokeInitWindow();
    }
    public void invokeInitWindow()
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        init();
                    }
                });

    }
    public void init()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void move()
    {
        newY=++newX;
        oldX=oldY=newX+1;
    }
    public void runGraph()
    {
        while(newX < 500)
        {
            move();
            repaint();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Graph g = new Graph();
        g.runGraph();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(oldX, oldY, newX, newY);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is, but you `while-loop` is running so fast that's finishing before the frame gets on the screen

Answer (score 0):

So, after adding some `System.out.println` commands about the place, it was obvious that you basically had a race condition.

That is, your `while-loop` was able to run so fast, it actually completed before the window was visible on the screen, so it was painting a point somewhere off the screen.

What you need to do, is inject a small delay into the loop to slow it down (and so a person can actually see it), something like...

```
public void runGraph() {
    while (newX < 500) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(40);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Graph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        move();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

## Code Review

Sorry, can't help myself.  One of the (significant) issues you code has is the fact that the constructor has a side-effect, that is, it's creating a `JFrame` and doing so, sometime in the future.  This is something you really want to avoid doing.  A constructor should initialise the state of the object and that's all.

The way you have it setup at the moment, you couldn't possibly re-use the panel in any meaningful way.

Secondly, you really should be calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting.  Painting is Swing is made up a series of method calls chained together, each doing a small, but important job, unless you know exactly what that method is doing and you're will to take over it's job, it's just simpler to call it's `super` method.

I'm guessing you're trying to draw a line which grows, so I've modified the `move` method, so the start of the line remains stationary.  I may have been your intention to have it move down the screen, in which case, it wouldn't be hard to reinstate the code as you had, I just wasn't sure

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Graph extends JPanel {

    private int oldX = 0, oldY = 0, newX = 1, newY = 1;

    public Graph() {
    }

    public void move() {
        newY = ++newX;
//      oldX = oldY = 
        newX += 1;
    }

    public void runGraph() {
        while (newX < 500) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(40);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Graph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            move();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Graph g = new Graph();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(g);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        g.runGraph();
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(oldX, oldY, newX, newY);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thank you for the quick and helpful comment, actually what i wanted was to 'graph' a bunch of these lines in a small enough interval that it would paint a graph. Im still struggling with this issue because it refreshes every time so what i get is a moving small line but it doesn't 'stay' where it was.

Comment: Paint is destructive, if you want to paint the graph in "chunks" then you need to maintain a `List` of those chunks and when `paintComponent` is called, paint them all again